# Como centralizar todo o layout

Tags: android, android-layout

Tenho o seguinte layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button>

    <TableLayout>android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

        (Aqui tem algumas <TableRows>)

    </TableLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

É preciso fazer com que ele todo fique centralizado verticalmente, desde o primeiro button até ao último, se mantendo organizados assim como estão. Tentei colocando `android:layout_centerVertical="true"` mas não funciona. O que eu devo fazer?

Comment: tenta usando `android:layout_centerInParent="true"`no primeiro nivel, eu, depois de muito sofrer com posicionamento de componentes na tela, vi que a melhor forma é ir aninhando linearlayouts e dentro deles as estruturas que eu preciso

Comment: não funcionou pra mim, coloquei no primeiro nível `<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true">`

Comment: posta o seu arquivo de layout na resposta pra poder ver o que pode ser feito

Comment: Muito obrigado Armando, mas eu consegui com um simples `android:gravity:"center"`, como eu não tinha feito isso antes? Não sei. Kk

Answer (score 1):

Tente usar o parametro `android:gravity="center_vertical"` no LinearLayout pai. Se quiser ajustar cada View separadamente, você pode usar o parametro `android:layout_gravity` na View desejada.